# Pandas DataFrame apply Specific Function to Each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['Var1']=np.random.randint(0,100,10)    
>>> df['Var2']=np.random.randint(0,10,10)   
>>> df
   Var1  Var2
0    46     2
1    10     3
2    30     6
3    49     4
4    62     3
5    64     8
6    26     0
7    41     2
8     3     2
9    22     3
>>>
```

And I have the following series that contains multiplication factors that each column will be multiplied by:

```
>>> MultFactors=pd.Series(index=['Var1','Var2'],data=np.random.randn(2))
>>> MultFactors
Var1    0.833691
Var2   -1.408577
dtype: float64
>>>
```

What is the best way to return a dataframe that is the same shape as the original dataframe and contains each value multiplied by the appropriate multiplication factor. I can do this with a for loop but am wondering what the more efficient way is.

```
>>> for MultFactor in MultFactors.index:
...     df[MultFactor]=df[MultFactor]*MultFactors[MultFactor]
... 
>>> df
        Var1       Var2
0  38.349773  -2.817155
1   8.336907  -4.225732
2  25.010722  -8.451464
3  40.850845  -5.634310
4  51.688825  -4.225732
5  53.356206 -11.268619
6  21.675959  -0.000000
7  34.181319  -2.817155
8   2.501072  -2.817155
9  18.341196  -4.225732
>>>
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't this get the same thing?

```
df = df * MultFactor
```

Comment: Wow. Yes - a lot easier than I had thought.

Comment: As long as the variable names match it will multiply matching variables.